# Rigged mesh intersecting and overlapping during posing process

Tags: animation, armature, rigify, motion-capture, intersection

I hope you're all having a great day!

I'm still very much a beginner when it comes to using Blender, and so far, I've just been playing around with it. I have a question about animating rigging.

Here's the thing: I created this animation using the BlendAr Mocap addon (created by CGTinker). Now, when I run the animation, there are parts of the mesh that intersect and overlap each other.

I want to ask, **is there a technique or trick** (like collision or rigid body, I'm really clueless about this) **that can prevent the armature pose from intersecting with other parts of the mesh?** Or maybe there's a free addon that can solve this problem?

Or is it simply not possible yet, and manual animation is the only way?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance from fellow forum members.

Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no fully automated method. Select the bones, whose rotations cause problems, identify the axis that needs to be fixed and in the Graph Editor shift/scale the keyframes of that channel. Alternatively you can use layers in the nla editor to add offsets to animation, but that is more advanced